# Why is the first response empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to get all the comments of a post , i am using expressjs with mongodb, but i have a little issue , the first response is always empty here's my code:

```
const Post = require("../models/posts"),
      Comment= require("../models/comments");
var commentsArray = [];

router.get("/post/:id/comments", async (req,res)=>{

        Post.findById(req.params.id).then( (post) => {
            post.comments.forEach(comment =>{
                if(commentsArray.length === 0  ){
                    Comment.findById(comment).then((comment)=>{
                        commentsArray.unshift(comment)
                    }); 
                 }
            });
        });
    
    return await res.json(commentsArray);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by first response

Comment: i meant the first time that i send a request to that route i get an empty response (nothing) but in the second request i get a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... Since `Post.findById` and `Comment.findById` are async functions the response is being returned before you fill your `commentsArray`. Additionally. using it as a global variable is bad practice because you will always return the previous results of other posts and duplicate the results on multiple calls on the same URI.

So... for resolving your issue `await` the `Post.findById` and `Comment.findById` before going forward. Additionally, for perfomance issues I recommend you review your need for using `Comment.findById`. There are ways where you could `$lookup` operator to do this in a single query.

```
const Post = require("../models/posts");
const User = require("../models/users");

router.get("/post/:id/comments", async (req,res)=> {
  if (! req.params.id) {
    // throw not found error
  }

  const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
  // is this really needed? is there anyway you can search for multiple items? if no...
  const comments = await Promise.all(
    post.comments.map(comment => Comment.findById(comment))
  );

  return res.json(comments);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you mix up `async/await` and `then` it's ugly. When using `asyn/await` you don't need `then` normally.

And that's normally it doesn't work because the return is executed before the `then` finishes.

I propose to you :

```js
const Post = require("../models/posts"),
User = require("../models/users");
var commentsArray = [];

router.get("/post/:id/comments", async (req,res)=>{
  const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

  try {
    
    await Promise.all(post.comments.map(async(comment) =>{
      if(comments.length === 0 && comment ){
        const comment2 = await Comment.findById(comment);
        commentsArray.unshift(comment2)
      }
    }));

    return res.json(commentsArray)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
})
```

Comment: And this `await res.json(commentsArray);` is not necessary because `res.json` is not a promise.

Comment: commentsArray will still return a wrong answer... because you're not awaiting all promises in the `.forEach`

Comment: you are right try with the new code to see

Answer (score 0):

Because `commentsArray` is on outer scope and your query is not using async/await. Also `forEach` is not blocking instead try this.

```
const Post = require("../models/posts"),
             User = require("../models/users");

router.get("/post/:id/comments", async (req,res)=>{
  try{
    const commentsArray = [];
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

    for(const item of post.comments){
      const comment = await Comment.findById(item)
      commentsArray.unshift(comment)             
    }

    return res.status(200).send(commentsArray);
  }catch(err){
    return res.status(500).send({message: 'Something went nuts'});
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `async/await` syntax completely.

Get the post then get the post's comments by ids:

```
const Post = require("../models/posts");
const User = require("../models/users");

router.get("/post/:id/comments", async (req, res) => {
  const comments = [];
  const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);

  for (const commentId of post.comments) {
    const comment = await Comment.findById(commentId);
    comments.unshift(comment);
  }
  return await res.json(comments);
});
```